# RichFaces column sort affecting multiple DataTables within the page

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

In my page I have two simple rich:extendedDataTable tables and each table has a sortable column and the data is sorted in ascending sortOrder by default. When I click on the sortable column to change the sortOrder direction in one table, the data in both tables will get re-sorted.

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:outputPanel id="id-healthPanel" style="float : left" layout="block"  ajaxRendered="true">
        <rich:panel styleClass="panelBackground" style="width:622px; height: 350px;">
            <rich:extendedDataTable id="policyHealthList" value="#{complianceMonitorManagedBean.allPendingHealthPolicies}" var="healthItem"
                  rows="#{complianceMonitorManagedBean.displayRows}" >

                  <f:facet name="header">
                      <h:outputText value="Health Policies with Missing Instructions" />
                  </f:facet>

                  <rich:column headerClass="alignLeft" width="60px">
                      <f:facet name="header">Policy</f:facet>
                      <h:outputText value="#{healthItem.policy}" />
                  </rich:column>

                  <rich:column headerClass="alignLeft" width="110px">
                      <f:facet name="header">Plan Code</f:facet>
                      <h:outputText value="#{healthItem.planCode}" />
                  </rich:column>

                  <rich:column sortOrder="#{complianceMonitorManagedBean.sortOrder}" sortBy="#{healthItem.sortKey}" headerClass="alignCenter" width="70px">
                      <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
                      <h:outputText value="#{healthItem.userDate}" />
                  </rich:column>

                  <f:facet name="footer">
                     <rich:dataScroller align="left" for="policyHealthList" maxPages="20"
                                    stepControls="hide" boundaryControls="hide" fastControls="hide" id="sc" />
                  </f:facet>

            </rich:extendedDataTable>

        </rich:panel>
    </a4j:outputPanel>

    <a4j:outputPanel id="id-lifePanel" style="float : left;" layout="block"  ajaxRendered="true">
        <rich:panel styleClass="panelBackground" style="width:729px; height: 350px;">

            <rich:extendedDataTable id="policyLifeList" value="#{complianceMonitorManagedBean.allPendingLifePolicies}" var="lifeItem" 
                rows="#{complianceMonitorManagedBean.displayRows}">
                  <f:facet name="header">
                      <h:outputText value="Life Policies with Missing Instructions" />
                  </f:facet>

                <rich:column headerClass="alignLeft" style="width:50px">
                      <f:facet name="header">Policy</f:facet>
                      <h:outputText value="#{lifeItem.policy}" />
                  </rich:column>

                   <rich:column headerClass="alignLeft" style="width:50px">
                      <f:facet name="header">Plan Code</f:facet>
                      <h:outputText value="#{lifeItem.planCode}" />
                  </rich:column>

                <rich:column headerClass="alignCenter" sortOrder="#{complianceMonitorManagedBean.sortOrder}" sortBy="#{lifeItem.sortKey}" style="width:50px">
                      <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
                      <h:outputText value="#{lifeItem.userDate}" />
                  </rich:column>

                  <f:facet name="footer">
                     <rich:dataScroller align="left" for="policyLifeList" maxPages="20"
                                    stepControls="hide" boundaryControls="hide" fastControls="hide" id="sc2" />
                  </f:facet>
            </rich:extendedDataTable> 

        </rich:panel>
    </a4j:outputPanel>

</h:form>
```

I figure I need to put each table in a separate region as in the `<a4:4region>` tag, but so far I have been unsuccessful sorting just the table I selected. Should I just use `<rich:jQuery click(function()...>` to handle the event? Can anyone suggest how to properly get the sorting/click event working for only the table I selected?

I'm using RichFaces 4.3.4-Final, JSF 2.2.6

Comment: The problem was I had included the ajaxRendered=true attribute in the outputPanels, which according the documentation means it will always update it [link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Basic_concepts.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Basic_concepts-Sending_an_Ajax_request). Once I removed that attribute from the outputPanels, the column sort worked as expected, it updated only the table I selected.

Comment: Both of the sortable columns point to the same variable, that's not a good idea, even if you limit the rerendering.